# Single stepping Guest OS instruction with AMD processor : Intel Monitor Trap Flag equivalent for AMD

Tags: debugging, x86, intel, virtualization, amd-processor

I am writing a debugger that should trace a guest OS execution in a virtual machine. Intel VMX Monitor Trap Flag field enables us to single step a guest OS instruction.

But I am working with AMD processor and I don't find in the documentation any equivalent for this. Does someone know if there is any AMD SVM equivalent for the Intel VTX Monitor Trap Flag ?

Comment: I have the same question, and probably AMD does not support it. By randomly searching on Google I see https://lore.kernel.org/all/20220128005208.4008533-23-seanjc@google.com/ : `/* SVM has no hyperversior debug trap (VMX's Monitor Trap Flag). */`